# setFixedSearchResults not working?

Tags: unit-test, sosl, namespace

I have a test method calling setFixedSearchResults with 5 ids, and then a method performing an SOSL search.

I expect my search to return 5 records. In fact, it did in my previous scratch org, test passed.
But now it returns an empty list, I don't know what could have changed...

**testMethod**

```
@isTest
static void test_searchCourse(){
    System.runAs(user){
        Test.startTest();
        List<Course__c> soslSearchedResult = [Select Id from Course__c limit :CourseRegistrationActionController.MAX_RESULTS];
        List<Id> idsSosl = getIdsList(soslSearchedResult);
        System.debug(idsSosl);     
        // => DEBUG|(a023N000004Dh88QAC, a023N000004Dh89QAC, a023N000004Dh8AQAS, a023N000004Dh8BQAS, a023N000004Dh8CQAS)
        Test.setFixedSearchResults(idsSosl);
        List<LookupSearchResult> res = CourseRegistrationActionController.searchCourse('Course', new List<String>());
        System.assertEquals( CourseRegistrationActionController.MAX_RESULTS, res.size()); 
        // => System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: 5, Actual: 0
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

**searchCourse method**

```
//...    some stuff here
List<List<SObject>> searchResults = [FIND :searchTerm IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Course__c (Id, Name, Description__c, LmsId__c, LMS__c WHERE id NOT IN :selectedIds) LIMIT :MAX_RESULTS];            
// => VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT [57]|searchResults|[[]]|0x4f2e07f4
System.debug(searchResults);    
// => DEBUG|(())
//...
```

I can't figure out why the SOSL doesn't return the records...

Answer (score 1):

It appears that I had to add my namespace in the SOSL search.
I can perform a SOQL query without a namespace and it works, as in :

```
 Select Id from Course__c
```

But an SOSL search without the namespace won't work :

```
FIND {term} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING
        Course__c (Id, Name, Description__c)
```

is not ok.

Instead I have to write

```
FIND {term} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING
        namespace__Course__c (Id, Name, namespace__Description__c)
```

I don't really get why, but that's how it seems to work.